# Is there a way to have a sync function that subscribes to an observable within it?

Tags: angular, observable

Assuming I have this code

observableMethod(): Observably {
...
Return of([1, 2, 3]);
}

notObservableMethod(): integer {

Let myVal;

if (isOM) {
this.observableMethod().pipe(
first()
).subscribe( val =>
myVal = val;
});
} else {
myVal = this.nonAsyncMethod();
}

return myVal * 5;
}

What can I do to notObservableMethod so it can return myVal * 5;? Meaning it has to be a syncronous method?

Edit: In reality, val is a url and I have a postProcess for that url that is more complex in the example I posted above before I navigate to it. Currently, what I did is create another method for the post process then call it in each condition or in a subscribe if its observable but I was thinking if there's a better way of doing it. Thank you!

Comment: Can you give more context on why you need notObservableMethod() ? Like are you trying to display it on the view ? html ? 

Are you trying to access that value at certain point ?

There is multiple ways to achieve what you are trying to do, so depending on context

Comment: Hello @ErenYeager, in reality, val is a url and i have a postProcess for that url that is more complex in the example I posted above before I navigate to it. Currently, what I did is create another method for the post process then call it in each condition or in a subscribe if its observable but I was thinking if there's a better way of doing it.

Comment: why do you not convert `notObservableMethod` to return `Observable<number>` then return or the first method or `of(myVal * 5)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am not entirely sure I understand the whole snippet, I'll try to guide you based on your example. I was trying to figure out if there could be a better way by using some RxJS operators along the way, before you subscribe, or a `async$` pipe in your template.

I would change your code above to something like this:

```
observableMethod(): Observably { ... Return of([1, 2, 3]); }

notObservableMethod(): Observable<number> {

  const observableSource = isOM ? this.observableMethod() : Observable.of(nonAsyncMethod());

  return observableSource.pipe(first(), map(val => val * 5)); 
}
```

Comment: You would then subscribe where you need to get the value to your method "notObservableMethod()" , which you should probably change the name here, this way you can access the value in your post process